# Tutorial rosmsg error

Tags: ros, python, rosmsg, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was learning ROS by doing the tutorials. But at tutorial 5 [(http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) at section 13.1 I encountered the following error:

```
s0214828@pma-09-043:/net/pma-robot-quad/home/nfs/s0214828$ rosmsg show turtlesim/Velocity 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros/bin/rosmsg", line 35, in <module>
    rosmsg.rosmsgmain()
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros_comm/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg.py", line 537, in rosmsgmain
    rosmsg_cmd_show(ext, full)
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros_comm/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg.py", line 421, in rosmsg_cmd_show
    rosmsg_debug(mode, arg, options.raw)
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros_comm/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg.py", line 285, in rosmsg_debug
    print get_msg_text(type_, raw=raw)
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros_comm/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg.py", line 255, in get_msg_text
    text = str(spec)
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/msgs.py", line 354, in __str__
    return _strify_spec(self)
  File "/home/s0214828/studentjob/ros-py3/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/msgs.py", line 249, in _strify_spec
    buff.write("%s%s %s\n"%(indent, type_, name))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

Thanks,
Peter

*EDIT*
My python version is : Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10492/tutorial-rosmsg-error/) by [Peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/790/peter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question hasn't been updated or commented on in over a month. Closing

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, I viewed the msgs.py file where the error came from. And I found this lines (240..244) where causing the error:

```
if buff is None:
    if sys.hexversion > 0x03000000: #Python3    
        buff = BytesIO()
    else:
        buff = StringIO
```

I noticed that StringIO is imported from cStringIO so it has to be a method. I added parentheses and changed the code to:

```
if buff is None:
    if sys.hexversion > 0x03000000: #Python3    
        buff = BytesIO()
    else:
        buff = StringIO()
```

And now the call to rosmsg works.

Am I the only one with a bug in the /ros-py3/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/msgs.py file?

---

Originally posted by [Peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/790/peter/) with karma: 36 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/790/peter/) on 2011-07-06**:
I didn't install it myself. Somebody helped me install it because it is installed on a lab computer to which I don't have all rights.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-06**:
How did you install ROS?